# C++ Custom User input command - Call Varibles

Tags: c++, command, game-engine

I appreciate the help. I am really bad at c++ and i like constructive criticism. im building a text based game and im currently setting up all the functions and systems. my problem is that i need a way for the user to be able to, at any time, type in somthing like "stats" and have them printed on the screen. currently i do not know how to do that. i dont know if this is possible but would i be able to have the stats always show. you know when your in the cmd and where it shows what directory your in, i would like it to be right there but in my game. heres the source, i know its cluttered

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ConsoleColor.h>
using namespace std;
//STAT VARS
int hp=100;
//Login VARS
const string USERNAME = "user";
const string PASSWORD = "123456";
string username, password;

int main()

{
login:
cout<< "================" <<endl;
cout<< "======Login=====" <<endl;
cout<< "================" <<endl;
cout<< "\n Username: ";
cin >> username;
cout<< endl;
cout<< "Enter Password : ";
cin >> password;
cout<< endl;
if(username == USERNAME && password == PASSWORD)
        {
            system("cls");
            cout << green << "CORRECT" <<white<< endl;
            Sleep(1000);
            system("cls");
            goto correct;
        }
        else
        {
            system("cls");
            cout <<red<< "Invalid login details" <<white<< endl;\
            Sleep(1000);
            system("cls");
            goto login;
        }
correct:
char name[20];
cout <<"What do they call you boy?" << endl;
cin.getline(name, 20);
cout << "You should keep moving, " << name << ".Were running out of daylight." << endl;
cout << "\n ***** Press Any Key To Continue *****" << endl;
_getch();
return 0;

}
```

Comment: question: do you *have* to do this in c++? If you want to learn (game) programming there are easier languages to do this in (ie Lua) and frameworks that allow you to focus on making games. I bet there's even a text adventure maker somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

### Remove `goto`

```
while ((username != EXPECTED_USERNAME)
       && (password != EXPECTED_PASSWORD))
{
  // No need to clear the screen.
  cout<< "\n Username: ";
  cin >> username;
  cout<< endl;
  cout<< "Enter Password : ";
  cin >> password;
  cout<< endl;
}
```

You should not have your identifiers differ only by case.  Although the compiler will treat `username` different from `USERNAME`, *Good Coding Guidelines* state that identifiers (names) should be more different.  This is why I used `username` and `EXPECTED_USERNAME` in the example above.  Something about better readability.

### Consistency

You used the `std::string` type for the `username`, yet you use `char [20]` for the boy's name.  Be consistent, use `std::string` for all the types.

### Pause for Enter

Trying to detect a keypress without pressing Enter is not as portable as waiting for them to press enter.
Try this:
  std::cout << "Press ENTER when ready.\n";
  std::cin.ignore(100000, '\n);

### Stop Clearing The Screen

Very annoying.  There may be information that could be retrieved by scrolling back, but you insist on clearing the screen.  Bad form.

### Don't Sleep

The input will wait for the User to press the Enter key, so there is no need to sleep.  The sleep is not portable.

Also, if you are going to fool people about entering bad passwords, you will need to sleep when they enter a valid password too.

### Don't use non-portable console tricks

In modern times, console programs are run in a window; maybe a terminal emulator.  The console windows are not standard.  Don't rely on colors or clearing the screen or moving the cursor.  Display what you need to each time.

If you want to use graphics, develop for a GUI application.

**Edit 1: Command Driven Architecture**
You will need to have a design or architect following this psuedo code:

```
While true
{
  Input User's text   
  if    User entered quit command, exit program.
  else  Execute a function based on the Users text  
}
```

This will allow the User to enter the command "stats" *at any time*.
If you want the User to enter commands while you are displaying text, it is possible, but adds more complication.

The actions of the game should be quick enough that the next command prompt is displayed before the User can enter "stats".

Comment: thanks for the criticism but doesn't answer my question

Comment: You need to redesign or re-architect your program.  Your program needs to input text from the User, then execute a function based on the input text.